# Share the same form across 2 bootstrap modal

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I have defined 2 bootstrap modal *'#Photographer' and '#Wildlifephotographer'.* Both of which contains nothing a but a registration form. In my case both the bootstrap modal shares almost the same form except that '#Wildlifephotographer' modal needs additional form fields than '#Photographer' modal.

**Photographer modal:**

```
<div id="Photographer" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
 <div class="modal-dialog">

<!-- Modal content-->
<div class="modal-content">
<input type="hidden" id="id" name="id" value="">
<input type="hidden" id="picture" name="picture" />


        <div class="modal-header resume-edit-model-header">                
            <h4 class="modal-title resume_form_title">Register As Photographer</h4>
        </div>         

        <div class="modal-body">
                     <div  id="regErrMsg"  class="gone"></div>              
                     <div  class="col-md-6">
                          <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="inputtitle" for="sName">Name</label>
                            <input type="text" placeholder="Enter username" id="sName" class="form-control" value="">
                        </div>      
                    </div> 

                     <div  class="col-md-6 pdg-none" >
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="inputtitle" for="sEmail">Email / Login*</label>
                            <input type="text" placeholder="Enter email" id="sEmail" class="form-control" value="">
                        </div>
                    </div>       
                   <div  class="col-md-6">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="inputtitle" for="reg_no">Password</label>
                            <input type="text" placeholder="Enter password again"  id="sPassword"  class="form-control" value="">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div  class="col-md-6 pdg-none" >
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="inputtitle" for="reg_no">Password Again*</label>
                            <input type="text" placeholder="Enter password again"  id="scPassword"  class="form-control" value="">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div  class="form-group" >
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="inputtitle" for="sMobile">Mobile</label>
                            <input type="text" placeholder="Enter mobile"  id="sMobile" class="form-control" value="">
                        </div>
                    </div>                  


                <div class="modal-footer resume-form-footer reg-sub">
                    <!-- button data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-default cancel-button" type="button">Cancel</button-->
                     <button onclick="javascript:registerValidationPhoto();" class="btn btn-primary submit-button" type="submit">Submit</button>
                </div>             
        </div>





</div>
```

**Wildlifephotographer modal:**

```
<div id="Wildlifephotographer" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">

<!-- Modal content-->
<div class="modal-content">
<input type="hidden" id="id" name="id" value="">
<input type="hidden" id="picture" name="picture" />


        <div class="modal-header resume-edit-model-header">                
            <h4 class="modal-title resume_form_title">Register As Wildlife Photographer</h4>
        </div>         

        <div class="modal-body">
                     <div  id="regErrMsg"  class="gone"></div>              
                     <div  class="col-md-6">
                          <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="inputtitle" for="sName">Name</label>
                            <input type="text" placeholder="Enter username" id="sName" class="form-control" value="">
                        </div>      
                    </div> 

                     <div  class="col-md-6 pdg-none" >
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="inputtitle" for="sEmail">Email / Login*</label>
                            <input type="text" placeholder="Enter email" id="sEmail" class="form-control" value="">
                        </div>
                    </div>       
                   <div  class="col-md-6">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="inputtitle" for="reg_no">Password</label>
                            <input type="text" placeholder="Enter password again"  id="sPassword"  class="form-control" value="">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div  class="col-md-6 pdg-none" >
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="inputtitle" for="reg_no">Password Again*</label>
                            <input type="text" placeholder="Enter password again"  id="scPassword"  class="form-control" value="">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div  class="form-group" >
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="inputtitle" for="sMobile">Mobile</label>
                            <input type="text" placeholder="Enter mobile"  id="sMobile" class="form-control" value="">
                        </div>
                    </div>                  

                   <div  class="form-group" >
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="inputtitle" for="reg_no">Address</label>                                
                             <textarea id="address"  placeholder="Enter address"  rows="5"  class="form-control"></textarea>
                        </div>
                    </div>               


                <div class="col-md-6 pdg-none">
                    <div class="form-group">
                         <label for="class_year" class="inputtitle">Country</label>
                       <div class="inputBox"><select onchange='getStateList();' name='sCountry' id='sCountry'><option value=''>---- Select ----</option><option value='105_ India ' ''> India </option></select></div>
                    </div>                        
                </div>

                <div  class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="inputtitle" for="percentage">State</label>                            
                        <div class="inputBox" id="stateList"><select id='sState'><option value=''>select state</option></select></div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div  class="col-xs-6 pdg-none" >
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="inputtitle" for="sCity">City</label>                                 
                             <div class="inputBox" id="cityList"><select id='sCity'><option value=''>select city</option></select></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>    

                <div class="modal-footer resume-form-footer reg-sub">
                    <!-- button data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-default cancel-button" type="button">Cancel</button-->
                     <button onclick="javascript:registerValidationPhoto();" class="btn btn-primary submit-button" type="submit">Submit</button>
                </div>             
        </div>





</div>
```

Is there any chance I can reuse the same form from `'#Photographer'` modal in `'#Wildlifephotographer'` modal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can do that as below:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#Photographer" data-whatever="Photographer">Register As Photographer</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#Photographer" data-whatever="Wildlife Photographer">Register As Wildlife Photographer</button>

<div id="Photographer" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
     <div class="modal-dialog">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
    <input type="hidden" id="id" name="id" value="">
    <input type="hidden" id="picture" name="picture" />


            <div class="modal-header resume-edit-model-header">                
                <h4 class="modal-title resume_form_title"></h4>
            </div>         

            <div class="modal-body">
                         <div  id="regErrMsg"  class="gone"></div>              
                         <div  class="col-md-6">
                              <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="inputtitle" for="sName">Name</label>
                                <input type="text" placeholder="Enter username" id="sName" class="form-control" value="">
                            </div>      
                        </div> 

                         <div  class="col-md-6 pdg-none" >
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="inputtitle" for="sEmail">Email / Login*</label>
                                <input type="text" placeholder="Enter email" id="sEmail" class="form-control" value="">
                            </div>
                        </div>       
                       <div  class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="inputtitle" for="reg_no">Password</label>
                                <input type="text" placeholder="Enter password again"  id="sPassword"  class="form-control" value="">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div  class="col-md-6 pdg-none" >
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="inputtitle" for="reg_no">Password Again*</label>
                                <input type="text" placeholder="Enter password again"  id="scPassword"  class="form-control" value="">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div  class="form-group" >
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="inputtitle" for="sMobile">Mobile</label>
                                <input type="text" placeholder="Enter mobile"  id="sMobile" class="form-control" value="">
                            </div>
                        </div>                  


                    <div class="modal-footer resume-form-footer reg-sub">
                        <!-- button data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-default cancel-button" type="button">Cancel</button-->
                         <button onclick="javascript:registerValidationPhoto();" class="btn btn-primary submit-button" type="submit">Submit</button>
                    </div>             
            </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**JS**:

```
$('#Photographer').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
  var button = $(event.relatedTarget) // Button that triggered the modal
  var recipient = button.data('whatever') // Extract info from data-* attributes
  // If necessary, you could initiate an AJAX request here (and then do the updating in a callback).
  // Update the modal's content. We'll use jQuery here, but you could use a data binding library or other methods instead.
  var modal = $(this)
  modal.find('.modal-title').text('Register As  ' + recipient)
})
```

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/Shaz4584/j48cngbh/1/embedded/result/)**

You can also refer [this bootstrap modal article](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals).